# Name that bearing!

Tags: bearings

Does anybody know the name of this type of bearing?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! I've embedded the image you linked to and removed your shopping request since [such questions are off-topic on this site](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832).

Answer (score 2):

"[Compact rail bearing](https://www.rollon.com/IN/en/products/linear-line/1-compact-rail/)" looks like a Timken subsidiary makes them.

Comment: I suppose you knew that from the image you posted. Not sure what the question is then...haha